# Check if there exists filename in directory

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, files

I have one file contains people name, like

```
Sam 
Tom
Dad
Jack
```

I have one directory that contains `name.txt` or `name.zip` which file's form is not the same, like

```
Dad.txt
Tom.zip
Jack.zip
```

How to find sam is not in directory?

Here is my thought:

```bash
input="people_name"

while IFS= read -r line
    do
    if [ -f "/my_files/${line}.zip"]|| [ -f "/my_files/${line}.txt" ] ; then
        echo "/${line} exists."
    else
        echo "/${line} does not exists."
    fi
done < "$input"
```

Output should be:

```
Sam does not exist
Tom exists
Dad exists
Jack exists
```

but terminal output :

```
Sam does not exist
Tom does not exists
Dad does not exists
Jack does not exists
```

Comment: what problem do you encounter? ... what is the output of the script?

Comment: ok I edit my output

Comment: So you want to test for bot suffixes? See if it is `.txt` OR `.zip`? => `if [ -f "${name}.zip" ] || [ -f "${name}.txt" ] ; then ...`

Comment: @TangPing please include the output you get now from the script you posted

Comment: Please indent all lines belonging to the script and its output by 4 space characters in order to render it as `code` (like the content of the do-loop is rendered now).

Comment: @sudosus ok I edit it

Comment: With the script you provided in its current form, the output would never be eg. `Tom.zip does not exists`, but rather `/my_files/Tom.zip line does not exists.` Please provide the exact script, input and related output.

Comment: @Vilinkameni No, it would output some variation of `[: missing ]` depending on the actual shell used, since there are a couple of missing space characters in the first test.

Comment: Please use https://www.shellcheck.net/ to locate and correct the most basic errors in your script. Then consider double-checking what your actual output is and update your question.

Comment: @they Of course. I was just focusing on the output of `echo`, which would never have matched the output quoted in the question as it was at the time of my comment.

Answer (score 1):

This script works, when run in the directory where you have the directory `my_files` and the file `people_name`:

```
#!/bin/bash

input="people_name"

while IFS= read -r line

    do

    if [ -f "my_files/${line}.zip" ] || [ -f "my_files/${line}.txt" ] ; then
        echo "${line} exists."
    else
        echo "${line} does not exist."
    fi
done < "$input"
```

with this input file:

```
Sam
Tom
Dad
Jack
```

Tweaks:

- added a 'shebang' as the first line to indicate that `bash` should run the script.
- added some spaces in the if statement
- removed the prefixing slashes, because I don't think you have the directory `my_files` in the root directory, and you do not want the output lines to start with a slash.

Comment: Note that there are no bashisms in the code, so you could have used `sh` in the `#!` line, or `zsh` for that matter.

Comment: @they, thanks for this comment., but `read` with the option `-r` does not work in `sh` (which is different from `bash`), so I think there is at least one reason to use the bash shebang, even if you might not call it a bashism.

Comment: The `-r` option te the `read` utility is a POSIX option. If you have a `sh` shell that does not support it, then you must be on an ancient system.

Comment: @they, Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS. I notice a difference between `bash` and `sh` how `read -r` is reading into a variable and how it is displayed by `echo`. Maybe there is [also?] a difference concerning the shell built-in `echo`.

Comment: Without any context, yes, there might be a difference in how `echo` works which depends on the string being outputted and the shell options that are active. Most noticeably, the interpretation of escape sequences like `\n` and `\t` may differ, and standard `echo` does not have _any_ options. This is why we tend to say that variable data should be outputted using `printf` rather than `echo` and that `echo` should only ever be used to output static strings.

Comment: So I should blame the difference on `echo` instead of `read -r`, and `echo` is not standardized even within `bash`. Thanks for this explanation, @they :-)

Comment: I still don't know what differences you are seeing, but `echo` is standardized. It's just that in `bash` it has extensions that may cause it to act differently under particular circumstances.  I mean, even standard `read` acts differently if you change the `IFS` variable...